# ExtJs window widget needs 5 seconds to load iframe

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, iframe, extjs4

I am using ExtJS 4 for my app, and when i click on a button I open an ExtJS window widget. I load an iframe in it and the iframe loads other controler that loads view from CodeIgniter MVC. So basically it goes like this

extjs window widget -> iframe -> controller -> view.

My problem is that the window widget needs about 5 seconds to load the controller, i.e see whatever output from it.

Any idea what is causing this problem? Is it the ExtJs problem here? Why it cant load the iframe it 1-2 seocnds or less?

Comment: "why can't I run a marathon in 20 minutes or less?" if you cut out the iframe and request the page served by CodeIgniter directly in your browser, how long does it take?

Comment: Good advice, it takes 4 seonds just for controller to load itself.

Comment: okay, so we now know it's related to the execution time of the page and not the fact it's in an iframe, the first thing to check is the number of queries